# Why these RAM don't work?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

I buy some RAM modules to increase the memory of desktop PCs.
I check the label of old module and looked for the same specs.

[image]

Then with this new memory the computer starts but after few minutes it restarts. 
How could I understand that is was incompatible?

I'm pretty sure that is not a failure because I bought many modules to replace many computer of same type, and no one is working.

Comment: Have you tried booting using each stick individually?

Comment: The two sticks are not identical.

Comment: Top one is  DDR3-1333 CL9 SDRAM 8gb, bottom is a DDR3-10600E 2GB - What is the ram inside the computer?

Comment: The bottom one is the original module

Comment: @JohnnyVegas yes, I tried to boot only with one lonely module, doesn't work.

Comment: PC3-10600 is not DDR3-1333?